# Get one progress for multiple ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using this code to preload certain files in parallel:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: "file1",
        xhrFields: {
          onprogress: function(e) {
             if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded / e.total * 100 + '%');
             }
          }
        },
        success: function() {
        }
    }),

    $.ajax({
        url: "file2",
        xhrFields: {
          onprogress: function(e) {
             if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded / e.total * 100 + '%');
             }
          }
        },
        success: function() {
        }
    }),

    $.ajax({
        url: "file3",
        xhrFields: {
          onprogress: function(e) {
             if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded / e.total * 100 + '%');
             }
          }
        },
        success: function() {
        }
    })

).then(function() {
    //all files are downloaded
});
```

The total download size is 22MB. I'm looking for a way to get the progress of all downloads combined, so I can make a progress bar.
For example, if 11MB of the total is downloaded, it should give me 50%.

Is this even possible in jQuery? Any tips?

**Update**:

OK, so I managed to get what I want, but it's not very pretty and feels like bad coding. Anyone knows a better way?

```
var totalSizeFile1;
var totalSizeFile2;
var totalSizeFile3;
var loadedFile1;
var loadedFile2;
var loadedFile3;

function downloadFiles() {
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            url: "file1",
            xhrFields: {
                onprogress: function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        totalSizeFile1 = e.total;
                        loadedFile1 = e.loaded;
                        totalProgress();
                    }
                }
            },
            success: function() {},
            error: function(request, status, error) {}
        }),

        $.ajax({
            url: "file2",
            xhrFields: {
                onprogress: function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        totalSizeFile2 = e.total;
                        loadedFile2 = e.loaded;
                        totalProgress();
                    }
                }
            },
            success: function() {},
            error: function(request, status, error) {}
        }),

        $.ajax({
            url: "file3",
            xhrFields: {
                onprogress: function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        totalSizeFile3 = e.total;
                        loadedFile3 = e.loaded;
                        totalProgress();
                    }
                }
            },
            success: function() {},
            error: function(request, status, error) {}
        })

    ).then(function() {
        //all files are downloaded
    });
}

function totalProgress()
{
    totalSize = totalSizeFile1 + totalSizeFile2 + totalSizeFile3;
    totalLoaded = loadedFile1 + loadedFile2 + loadedFile3;
     totalProgress = Math.round(totalLoaded/totalSize * 100);
}
```

Comment: Listen to the [progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event) of each request individually and do some simple math to get the total progress.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I managed to listen to them individually (see updated question), but how can I now merge them into one number that is updated as long as one of them is not at 100% yet? I'm not looking for the math obviously but rather a way to achieve this in jQuery.

Comment: If you always have exactly three files your solution is perfectly fine. You should put that in an answer and mark it accepted. Then, if you want more style advice or such you should go ask for that at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).